# Silence a small section of just one channel in a stereo recording (Audacity)

Tags: editing, audacity

I need to erase (silence) about 2 seconds of just one channel of a 2-channel stereo recording. I can use Audacity (or Ardour). I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Sorry to down vote, it's just to show the mods on the meta part of the site what we don't see as appropriate sound design questions. There's nothing wrong with the question per se, just the forum it's in IMHO.

Comment: I second ErikG.

Comment: I looked and saw other similar questions posted here before I posted this. You guys should be consistent. I feel singled out unfairly given the existing content.

Comment: Hi MountainX, i understand your feelings. You did nothing wrong and indeed there are similar questions on this forum. However, these questions are the result of a big transfer phase of 2 forums into 1. We are still weeding out all the stuff that we feel is not 'interesting enough'. 'Interesting' would be a question about sound design that challenges our thoughts and fixed opinions about how we do things. Or perhaps goes into depth on a specific issue during a creative process working on a film, game or a radioplay for example. So please forgive us for being 'rude'. Good luck finding an answer!

Comment: Audacity has a helpful online manual that explains all it's functions, and there are endless YouTube tutorials.

Comment: Manuals are one thing, common questions with answers are quite another.  Internet search got me here, saw the answer, and I'm cookin' with gas in seconds. Upvoted!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Audacity, you can approach this in at least two ways, depending on the nature of the bit you want to silence and the surrounding material.

The simple way is to highlight the section of the track / channel and select "Generate... Silence" from the menu. The suggested duration will be the length of your selection. This is a harsh edit, and very likely objectionable. You can ease that by insuring that your selection begins and ends at a zero crossing in the waveform. If you make the silence somewhat shorter and centered, you can fade out/fade in to soften the transition.

Another way would be to use 'envelope' mode, ramping down and up to cover the area. This is more or less the same thing as fade out/in above.

Again, depending on the nature of the sound, it might be possible to duplicate the channel you don't want to remove, into the silence you created. I'd do that by creating another track and copying the duplicate material, say from channel "A", into channel "B" and  crossfading in and out of it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

MountainX,

I don't know if you ever got the answer you needed but I just found out how to do it. If you have a stereo recording in Audacity you click on "Audio Track" at the left of the stereo channel you're looking for. You'll see Split Stereo Track in the drop down menu and then you can edit a specific segment of the audio in that channel alone

Comment: Alternatively... you can highlight the portion then just ctrl + L to silence that portion of the audio